# How to make a proper selection of an element's value from a BsonDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

So i explain, i have a controller that saves two informations in database. And the id is taken from one document to another one. I achieve this but my id is saved that way :

```
_id=57629cb900a09432b8b3ada4
```

But i want it like this :

```
57629cb900a09432b8b3ada4
```

I can't see how to do it because i'm taking the fist element of the bson document with the first() method.

If someone can help i put my controller just here :

EDIT : ADDED THE CODE PROVIDED BY @P57 (thanks to him) :

```
var id = objDocument[_id];
```

Becomes

```
string id = objDocument.GetElement("_id").Value.ToString();
```

So we have now :

```
public ActionResult LancerComparaison(ResultViewModel resultViewModel)
{
    if (resultViewModel!= null)
    {
        UserInformationViewModel info = resultViewModel.UserInformationViewModel;
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var objDatabase = client.GetDatabase("Test");
        var collection = objDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UsersInformations");
        BsonDocument objDocument = new BsonDocument {
        {"Nom",info.NomUser},
        {"Prenom",info.PrenomUser},
        {"Email",info.EmailUser},
        };
        collection.InsertOne(objDocument);
        string id = objDocument.GetElement("_id").Value.ToString();
        Session["IdentifiantUserInformation"] = id;

        List<ObjetTransfert> listePrestationsObjetsTransferts = new List<ObjetTransfert>();
        ResultatComparaison resultatComparaison;
        ConvertGViewModelToGBd(resultViewModel, listePrestationsObjetsTransferts);
        _compaSBT.ComparerP(listePrestationsObjetsTransferts, out resultatComparaison,
            Enums.E.T);

        //Enregistrer d'abord le resultat en Bd
        resultatComparaison.IdentifiantResultatComparaison = new Guid().ToString();
        resultatComparaison.IdentifiantUserInformation = id.ToString();
        _resultatComparaisonService.Create(resultatComparaison);

        Session["IdentifiantResultatComparaison"] = resultatComparaison.Id;


        return View();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
string id = objDocument.GetElement("_id").Value
```

Instead of this...

```
var id = objDocument.First()
```

Comment: That seems to be good but i did this  var id = objDocument["_id"] but seems it was not the right way, i'm getting the bad id but with your GetElement it's ok :) so thanks !

Comment: Glad it helped. You may want to rephrase the title of your question because it's misleading. @SurenSrapyan provided what it asks for, that is, the inverse action of concatenate which is `split`, but what you really needed was proper selection of an element's value from a BsonDocument .

Comment: You're right, i made the change, maybe it will help some other people

Answer (score 1):

Use **Split** method.It will split the string into the array. The splitting character is given as the first parameter.

```
string[] tokens = "_id=57629cb900a09432b8b3ada4".Split('=');
tokens[0]; // _id
tokens[1]; // 57629cb900a09432b8b3ada4
```

In your code you can write instead of this

```
var id = objDocument.First()
```

this

```
var id = objDocument.First().Split('=')[1];
```

Comment: Hmm seems legit but i don't have my string, it's saved throught a bson document. I don't see how to make this work with my code

Comment: @ChristianPliso in your C#, are you getting the string?

Comment: I'm just saving the id of the object and in my db it saved the way i did and i'd like to save only the id

Comment: @ChristianPliso what is the problem that in your bson you have the wrong syntax? As I guess, you will work with the id in the C# code, and that time you can split it

Comment: Yes in my bson i have the wrong syntax. but how can i split it whith substring ? i can't give a value to tokens in my code

Comment: @ChristianPliso Split, not Substring. Method is the Split()

Comment: Yes sorry, but still. I can't use Split in this context, well maybe i don't know how. It says that Split is not contained inside BsonElement

Comment: @ChristianPliso Where do you get your ID in the code?

Comment: Here  var id = objDocument.First(). But this is a BsonDocument.

Comment: @ChristianPliso Can you use like objDocument["id"].AsString and see what it returns?

Comment: Ok could not do it like this but see my edit ! It worked. I've putted this var id = objDocument[_id]; Thanks

Comment: @ChristianPliso Oh yes, your key is _id